# Why does ENcoding a string result in a DEcoding error (UnicodeDecodeError)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.x, python-unicode

I'm really confused. I tried to encode but the error said `can't decode...`.

```
>>> "你好".encode("utf8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know how to avoid the error with "u" prefix on the string. I'm just wondering why the error is "can't decode" when encode was called.  What is Python doing under the hood?

Comment: Note that this issue is fixed in 3.x: strings are simply Unicode and `bytes` objects are simply raw bytes, and never the twain shall meet. Strings don't do any implicit decoding when `.encode` is called; in fact, `.encode` is *not supported at all*, as it makes no sense. The weird behaviour was only present in 2.x as a compatibility hack in the first place, because of the way that Unicode was introduced into the language.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
"你好".encode('utf-8')
```

`encode` converts a unicode object to a `string` object. But here you have invoked it on a `string` object (because you don't have the u). So python has to convert the `string` to a `unicode` object first. So it does the equivalent of

```
"你好".decode().encode('utf-8')
```

But the decode fails because the string isn't valid ascii. That's why you get a complaint about not being able to decode.

Comment: So what is the solution? Especially if I don't have a string literal, I just have a string object.

Comment: @JonTirsen, you should not be encoding a string object. A string object is already encoded. If you need to change the encoding, you need to decode it into a unicode string and then encode it as the desired encoding.

Comment: So to state it clearly from above you can `"你好".decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @WinstonEwert I guess I was confused. The encoding business tend to leave me eternally confused. I guess my confusion came from my own problem of not knowing the if the input is a string or unicode string and what encoding it may have.

Comment: @deinonychusaur, yeah... I get that.

Comment: Fantastic aphorism mate!! all are lucid now.. I did not know that `encode` converts an unicode into `STRING` (i.e. without leading `u`)!! But this string is like `\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd` byte but if you print them they print fine as @wim explained

Answer (score 55):

Always *encode* from unicode to bytes.
In this direction, **you get to choose the encoding**.

```
>>> u"你好".encode("utf8")
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
>>> print _
你好
```

The other way is to decode from bytes to unicode.
In this direction, **you have to know what the encoding is**.

```
>>> bytes = '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
>>> print bytes
你好
>>> bytes.decode('utf-8')
u'\u4f60\u597d'
>>> print _
你好
```

This point can't be stressed enough.  If you want to avoid playing unicode "whack-a-mole", it's important to understand what's happening at the data level.  Here it is explained another way:

- A unicode object is decoded already, you never want to call `decode` on it.
- A bytestring object is encoded already, you never want to call `encode` on it.

Now, on seeing `.encode` on a byte string, Python 2 first tries to implicitly convert it to text (a `unicode` object).  Similarly, on seeing `.decode` on a unicode string, Python 2 implicitly tries to convert it to bytes (a `str` object).

These implicit conversions are why you can get `Unicode`**`Decode`**`Error` when you've called **`encode`**.  It's because encoding usually accepts a parameter of type `unicode`; when receiving a `str` parameter, there's an implicit decoding into an object of type `unicode` before re-encoding it with another encoding.  This conversion chooses a default 'ascii' decoder<sup>†</sup>, giving you the decoding error inside an encoder.

In fact, in Python 3 the methods `str.decode` and `bytes.encode` don't even exist.  Their removal was a [controversial] attempt to avoid this common confusion.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>...or whatever coding `sys.getdefaultencoding()` mentions; usually this is 'ascii'</sub>

Comment: So do you mean that Python decodes the bytestring before encoding?

Comment: @thoslin exactly, I added more details.

Comment: What is _, and why are your print statements missing parenthesis?

Comment: @NoBugs  1. in the REPL, `_` refers to the previous value  2.  because this is a python-2.x question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For my case the right solution was just .decode('utf-8'). I ran Subprocess.popen(...).communicate() which returned bytes containing German characters ä, ö, ü and the normal .decode() (without 'utf-8' parameter) failed. With 'utf-8' parameter it works.

Answer (score 42):

**You can try this**

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Or

**You can also try following**

Add following line at top of your .py file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: This must be accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Python < 3, you'll need to tell the interpreter that your [string literal is Unicode by prefixing it with a `u`](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan 14 2012, 23:14:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "你好".encode("utf8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u"你好".encode("utf8")
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
```

**Further reading**: [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto).

Comment: If you're encoding a string, why does it throw a decode error?

Comment: @MxLDevs because you can't get a decode error on an encode action.

Answer (score 4):

In case you're dealing with Unicode, sometimes instead of `encode('utf-8')`, you can also try to ignore the special characters, e.g.

```
"你好".encode('ascii','ignore')
```

or as [`something.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')` as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19528927/55075).

Not particularly useful in this example, but can work better in other scenarios when it's not possible to convert some special characters.

Alternatively you can consider [replacing particular character using `replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19528853/55075).

Answer (score 3):

You use `u"你好".encode('utf8')` to encode an unicode string.
But if you want to represent `"你好"`, you should decode it. Just like:

```
"你好".decode("utf8")
```

You will get what you want. Maybe you should learn more about encode & decode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting the python interpreter from a shell on Linux or similar systems (BSD, not sure about Mac), you should also check the default encoding for the shell.

Call `locale charmap` from the shell (not the python interpreter) and you should see

```
[user@host dir] $ locale charmap
UTF-8
[user@host dir] $
```

If this is not the case, and you see something else, e.g.

```
[user@host dir] $ locale charmap
ANSI_X3.4-1968
[user@host dir] $
```

Python will (at least in some cases such as in mine) inherit the shell's encoding and will not be able to print (some? all?) unicode characters. Python's own default encoding that you see and control via `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and `sys.setdefaultencoding()` is in this case ignored.

If you find that you have this problem, you can fix that by

```
[user@host dir] $ export LC_CTYPE="en_EN.UTF-8"
[user@host dir] $ locale charmap
UTF-8
[user@host dir] $
```

(Or alternatively choose whichever keymap you want instead of en_EN.) You can also edit `/etc/locale.conf` (or whichever file governs the locale definition in your system) to correct this.