# How to encode and decode from spanish in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have the following code written in python 2.7

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import sys

_string = "años luz detrás"
print _string.encode("utf-8")
```

this throws the following error:

```python
print _string.encode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You dont need to use encode, try only "print _string"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `u` before the `"`

```
>>> _string = u"años luz detrás"
>>> print _string.encode("utf-8")
años luz detrás
```

This would do.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2 a string literal `""` creates a bytestring. Then you call `.encode("utf-8")` on a bytestring, Python tries first to decode it into Unicode string using a default character encoding (`ascii`) before executing `.encode("utf-8")`.

`u""` creates Unicode string. It will fix the UnicodeDecodeError as [@Bleeding Fingers suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935202/4279).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
print u"años luz detrás"
```

It might lead to `UnicodeEncodeError` if stdout is redirected. Set `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable in this case.