# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters due to Ã©Ã©n from database

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode, non-unicode

I have a field to get from database which contains string with this part  Ã©Ã©n and while getting this i get error:

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-15: ordinal not in range(128)"

I have search this error, and other people were having issue due to unicodes which start something like this `u'\xa0`, etc. But in my case, i think its due to special characters. I can not do changes in database as its not under my access. I can just access it.

The code is here: (actually its call to external url)

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
res = urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout = 50)         #50 secs timeout
clientid = res.read()
result = json.loads(clientid)
```

Then I use result variable to get the above mentioned string and I get error on this line:

```
updateString +="name='"+str(result['product_name'])+"', "
```

Comment: Show the code where you "use result variable ... and get error"

Comment: Where is the call to the database and which line shows the error?

Comment: it crashes here when i try to concat it with my update query i.e. updateString +="name='"+str(result['product_name'])+"', " on this line gives me error

Comment: i donot have a database call, i just call the API, it gives me json data and i use it further , but gives me error as mentioned in above comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the encoding for which is used for your data before it's inserted into the database. Let's assume it's UTF-8 since that's the most common.

In that case you will want to UTF-8 decode instead of ascii decode. You didn't provide any code, so I'm assuming you have `"data".decode()`. Try `"data".decode("utf-8")`, and if your data was encoded using this encoding, it will work.

Comment: I tried your above mentioned solution, it gave a different error this time i.e.
s = obj['product_name'].decode("utf8")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-15: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: So it crashes on json.loads? Or is there another spot?

Comment: it crashes here when i try to concat it with my update query i.e.  
updateString +="name='"+str(result['product_name'])+"', "
on this line gives me error

Comment: Then perhaps your encoding is not `utf-8`. Try to find what encoding is used.

Comment: my apologies its "decoding Unicode is not supported" error now.

Comment: That must be another line then. We aren't "decoding Unicode" on the line I provided you.

Comment: I used your code like this
updateString +="name='"+unicode(result['product_name'], 'utf8')+"', "

gives me this error:
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Comment: So it sounds to me like the string already was unicode then. So remove str() and unicode functions on that line.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds to me like the string already was unicode then. So remove `str()` and `unicode` functions on that line.