# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

when I try to concatenate this, I get the UnicodeDecodeError when the field contains 'ñ' or '´'. If the field that contains the 'ñ' or '´' is the last I get no error.

```
#...

nombre = fabrica
nombre = nombre.encode("utf-8") + '-' + sector.encode("utf-8")
nombre = nombre.encode("utf-8") + '-' + unidad.encode("utf-8")

#...

return nombre
```

any  idea? Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You are encoding to UTF-8, then *re*-encoding to UTF-8. Python can only do this if it first *decodes* again to Unicode, but it has to use the default ASCII codec:

```
>>> u'ñ'
u'\xf1'
>>> u'ñ'.encode('utf8')
'\xc3\xb1'
>>> u'ñ'.encode('utf8').encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Don't keep encoding; leave encoding to UTF-8 *to the last possible moment* instead. Concatenate Unicode values instead.

You can use `str.join()` (or, rather, `unicode.join()`) here to concatenate the three values with dashes in between:

```
nombre = u'-'.join(fabrica, sector, unidad)
return nombre.encode('utf-8')
```

but even encoding here might be too early.

Rule of thumb: decode the moment you receive the value (if not Unicode values supplied by an API already), encode only when you have to (if the destination API does not handle Unicode values directly).

Comment: I think the rule of thumb here is the key point. It could be worded - "encode and decode only on API boundaries, and then only if you have to".

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Was banging my head against what I thought was a "simple" convert... and your note about double encoding was spot on.

Answer (score 14):

When you get a `UnicodeEncodeError`, it means that somewhere in your code you convert directly a byte string to a unicode one. By default in Python 2 it uses ascii encoding, and utf8 encoding in Python3 (both may fail because not every byte is valid in either encoding)

To avoid that, you must use explicit decoding.

If you may have 2 different encoding in your input file, one of them accepts any byte (say UTF8 and Latin1), you can try to first convert a string with first and use the second one if a UnicodeDecodeError occurs.

```
def robust_decode(bs):
    '''Takes a byte string as param and convert it into a unicode one.
First tries UTF8, and fallback to Latin1 if it fails'''
    cr = None
    try:
        cr = bs.decode('utf8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        cr = bs.decode('latin1')
    return cr
```

If you do not know original encoding and do not care for non ascii character, you can set the optional `errors` parameter of the `decode` method to `replace`. Any offending byte will be replaced (from the standard library documentation):

> Replace with a suitable replacement character; Python will use the official U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER for the built-in Unicode codecs on decoding and ‘?’ on encoding.

```
bs.decode(errors='replace')
```

Comment: This is not directly an answer to present question but to [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42410322/3545273) that was closed as a duplicate. At least it is related because of a UnicodeDecodeError and users searching for the error will find this answer...

Answer (score -9):

I was getting this error when executing in python3,I got the same program working by simply executing in **`python2`**

Comment: Downgrading python is not a reasonable solution to this problem