# UnicodeDecodeError after wrongly indenting def __unicode__(self): in models.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-admin

I had accidentally misplaced the tab indentation of two `def __unicode__(self):` methods in my models.py. I.e. for two models, I had done the following:

```
class Notification(models.model):
     recipient = models.OneToOneField(User)
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
          return "%s recieved a notification" % self.recipient
```

The `def` statement was at the same level as the class, the `return` statement was indented as if the method header was properly indented.

I corrected it and pushed to production (a Postgres setup w/ Heroku). If I access the admin panel locally (on SQLite), these data models populate correctly now. But if I try to access the admin panel of my live app, I get a 500 response and through NewRelic, I find that:

**exceptions:UnicodeDecodeError
/django.contrib.admin.options:changelist_view
exceptions:UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 68: ordinal not in range(128)**

I looked at similar questions such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475393/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-23-ordinal), but they don't seem to apply to my case. What is `django.contrib.admin.options:changelist_view`, and what exactly is that error trying to tell me. I need help in resolving this guys.

p.s. this pertains to a legacy project using *Django 1.5* and *Python 2.7*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning a Unicode object not a string object.

Assuming `self.recepient` is a Unicode already, do:

```
return u"%s recieved a notification" % self.recipient
```

Note the **u**