# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError when reading file with danish characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, unicode-normalization

I have read through similar questions on stack overflow, however non of them solve the unicode problem I have: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 302.

Have tried:
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

however receive an error: NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

I try to read file with danish vowels: æ, ø, å. In return receive 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 position 302 etc. 
Position 302 and further on include danish vowels. Is there a way to fix this?

So far I have tried putting a specially-formatted comment as the first line of the source code: `# -*- coding: <ascii> -*-`.  Did not give any result.

Also tried: `f = open(fname, encoding="ascii", errors="surrogate escape")`. But instead of reading file with characters as they are for example in the word "Europæiske" I get "Europ\udcc3\udca6iske".

Then I tried suggestions from the blog (lost a link to that blog) to "import unicodedata", however, it was not well explained where to take it form there.

```
import unicodedata
import csv

with open('File.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475393/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-23-ordinal)

Comment: kchomski, not trying to concatenate but rather read file with danish characters, it is a different case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply open with the correct encoding.  You have to know the encoding that the file was saved in.  Western versions of Windows might be `Windows-1252`, or perhaps `utf8`.  Modules such as [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) can perform an educated guess. Also, for for `csv` module, open with `newline=''` as well (see documentation for using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv

with open('File.csv',encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

that `#-- coding:` thing is only for what's being used *in the program itself*, for example if you define a variable or function with Danish characters.

what you're dealing with is I/O, so remember the rule: bytes on the edges, Unicode inside. this means use `str.decode` when reading in, and `unicode.encode` when writing out.

Comment: Thank you @jcomeau_ictx I understand the problem better now!