# How to handle Encoding Errors in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, nltk, python-unicode

I am working on parsing a large number (90000) csv files. Some of the files are converted to text from pdf. So, they have a lot of noise in the form of weird characters. For example, Cachï¿. Some of these files have been converted online and some through pdfminer. Now, in my program I parse the files and remove the stop words.

```
cleanedRow = ' '.join([word for word in row[1].split() if word not in stopWrds])
```

But due to these weird encoding/decoding issues, my program fails. I cannot delete all such characters searching through 90000 files. The program throws the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there an elegant way to ignore these characters in python?. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: The most elegant way to handle encodings is to upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: You have to have some idea what the encoding in question is. Trying Python3 might help some but fundamentally, you have to know or guess the encoding.

Comment: Are the files utf-8 compliant? If so, try to explicitly decode them via utf-8 (decode method) instead of the very limited ascii codec.

Comment: These files are given to me from a different source so I have no idea what encoding has been used while converting them.

Comment: 0xc3 could point to UTF-8...

Comment: `>>> 'Caché'.encode('utf-8')` -> `b'Cach\xc3\xa9'`

Comment: Is there a way to ignore such characters without the program failing?

Comment: @nltk: Unsure that it is a duplicate because OP does not explicitely use `decode` not knows the original encoding. Anyway, I have posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42411093/3545273) in the other question

Comment: There's nothing elegant in ignoring single characters – it will leave you with broken text. You can decode with `errors="ignore"`, but that's definitely not elegant. You should try to guess the correct encoding. If UTF8 works, you'll be done quickly.

Comment: That's fine if for now I get broken text. I need a quick solution. I'll most definitely try to get it done elegantly later