# __main__.py: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'blabla\xc3\xa9blabla', 31, 32, 'ordinal not in range(128)')

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

This is a common problem where I have respected the following rules (but probably wrongly):

- decode inputs
- encode outputs
- work in utf8 in between

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
        m = dict()
        with io.open('test.json','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            m = json.load(f)
        with io.open("test.csv",'w', encoding="utf-8") as ficS:
            line = list()
            for i in m['v']:
                v = m['v']['u']
                line.append(v['label'].replace("\n", " - "))
            ficS.write(';'.join(line).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Without `.encode('utf-8')`, it works, but the file is barely readable due to accentuated letters. With it, I have the following error message:

```
__main__.py: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'blabla\xc3\xa9blabla', 31, 32, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475393/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-23-ordinal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte?rq=1), it is said:

> You are encoding to UTF-8, then re-encoding to UTF-8. Python can only
>   do this if it first decodes again to Unicode, but it has to use the
>   default ASCII codec. Don't keep encoding; leave encoding to UTF-8 to
>   the last possible moment instead. Concatenate Unicode values instead.

Any idea please?

Comment: `line.append(v['label'].replace(u"\n", u" - "))` - once you have decoded, make sure you always use unicode strings when mutating the unicode string.  Otherwise Python2 may try to to coerce between the two types.

Comment: I have already tried, also in `ficS.write(u';'.join(line).encode('utf-8') + u'\n')` but without success

Comment: Don't manually `.encode('utf8')`. Leave this work to the `ficS` filehandle. So the last line should read: `ficS.write(u';'.join(line) + u'\n')`

Comment: If the accentuated letters look distorted in the resulting file, then this is most probably because MS Excel (or whatever tool you use to open) doesn't recognise UTF-8. In that case, try a different encoding for the output file, eg. `"utf-8-sig"` or `"utf16"`.