# UnicodeDecodeError in NLTK's word_tokenize despite I forced the encoding

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, nltk, pdfminer

I first convert a pdf into plain text (I print it out and everything is fine) and then I get a UnicodeDecodeError when I try to run word_tokenize() from NLTK.

I get that error despite I try to decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8') on the plain text, beforehand. In the traceback I noticed that the line of code from word_tokenize() that raises the error first is plaintext.split('\n'). This is why I tried to reproduce the error by running split('\n') on the plain text but still, that doesn't rise any error either.

So, I understand neither what is causing the error nor how to avoid it.

Any help would be greatly appreciate it! :) maybe I could avoid it by changing something in the pdf_to_txt file?

Here's the code to tokenize:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import os
import string
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

stopset = stopwords.words('english')
path = 'my_folder'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
        text = self.convert_pdf_to_txt(path+infile)
        text = text.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8').lower()
        print text
        splitted = text.split('\n')
        filtered_tokens = [i for i in word_tokenize(text) if i not in stopset and i not in string.punctuation]
```

Here's the method I call in order to convert from pdf to txt:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(self, path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    ret = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return ret
```

Here's the traceback of the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iammyr/opt/workspace/task-logger/task_logger/nlp/pre_processing.py", line 65, in <module>
    obj.tokenizeStopWords()
  File "/home/iammyr/opt/workspace/task-logger/task_logger/nlp/pre_processing.py", line 29, in tokenizeStopWords
    filtered_tokens = [i for i in word_tokenize(text) if i not in stopset and i not in string.punctuation]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 93, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
  [...]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 586, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thanks a million and loads of good karma to you! ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "plain text"? What encoding do you have in the file?

Comment: Also what's the point of decoding and then immediately encoding? I'm guessing removing the `.encode('utf-8')` would fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, tripleee, thank you so much for your help! Indeed removing the encoding worked, thanks a lot :) The reason I was decoding and encoding again was because I had read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte and the codec of the "plain text" was already utf-8 as you can see in convert_pdf_to_txt(). that's part of why i was puzzled as even the decoding shouldn't have been necessary, but still it was. thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are turning a piece of perfectly good Unicode string (back) into a bunch of untyped bytes, which Python has no idea how to handle, but desperately tries to apply the ASCII codec on.  Remove the `.encode('utf-8')` and you should be fine.

See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html