# ascii codec cant decode byte 0xe9

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, decode

I have done some research and seen solutions but none have worked for me.

[Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

This didn't work for me. And I know the 0xe9 is the é character. But I still can't figure out how to get this working, here is my code

```
output_lines = ['<menu>', '<day name="monday">', '<meal name="BREAKFAST">', '<counter name="Entreé">', '<dish>', '<name icon1="Vegan" icon2="Mindful Item">', 'Cream of Wheat (Farina)','</name>', '</dish>', '</counter >', '</meal >', '</day >', '</menu >']
output_string = '\n'.join([line.encode("utf-8") for line in output_lines])
```

And this give me the error `ascii codec  cant decode byte 0xe9`

And I have tried decoding, I have tried to replace the "é" but can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: Your code sample is invalid and won't reproduce the issue; `output_lines` is empty so your loop won't do anything. Your error indicates you have a **decoding** error while encoding, this usually indicates you are trying to encode data that is **already** encoded.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry I didn't show it was full in my sample code but it is filled. I will add that to the question

Comment: this is still not your actual `output_lines` ... surely ... can you `print output_lines` right before you try to create `output_string`

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes but but `output_lines` is must longer so I shortened it

Comment: Your data is **already encoded**, why do you feel the need to encode again?

Comment: @iqueqiorio unfortunately you did more than shorten it ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: it reproduces the problem, I don't see why more is needed?

Comment: @MartijnPieters cause surely it is an encoded acute e ... and we should see the escape code not the encoded character... and it clearly doesnt reprocuce the issue per comments on your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to encode bytestrings:

```
>>> '<counter name="Entreé">'.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Python is trying to be helpful, you can only encode a *Unicode* string to bytes, so to encode Python first implictly *decodes*, using the default encoding.

The solution is to *not encode* data that is already encoded, or first decode using a suitable codec before trying to encode again, if the data was encoded to a different codec than what you needed.

If you have a mix of unicode and bytestring values, decode just the bytestrings or encode just the unicode values; try to avoid mixing the types. The following decodes byte strings to unicode first:

```
def ensure_unicode(v):
    if isinstance(v, str):
        v = v.decode('utf8')
    return unicode(v)  # convert anything not a string to unicode too

output_string = u'\n'.join([ensure_unicode(line) for line in output_lines])
```

Comment: afaik this also indicates he is using python2x ... since in 3x it no longer tries to implicitly convert things and you get a much clearer error (+1 ofc)

Comment: @JoranBeasley and Martijn when I change it to `output_string = '\n'.join([line for line in output_lines])` I still get the same error?

Comment: @iqueqiorio: do you have a *mix* of Unicode and byte strings in your list?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think, so it is a long list is there a way to check with an if statement

Comment: then you need to post the actual input that is causing an error ... maybe put it in a dpaste ... but as it is we cannot replicate your issue ... and you should post a full traceback ...

Comment: @iqueqiorio: that's not a link to a gist; don't worry though, I have it covered.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thats a good solution  :) (one i have had to use before ... I still think its better to have well formed input)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I got the same error and an error on the line `v = v.decode("utf8")`

Comment: surely not `UnicodeDecodeError: ascii codec cannot ...`

Comment: I get `Unicode Decode: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte`

Comment: try `v.decode("latin1")` ... this is where its really handy to know the encoding you are using ahead of time ;P ... just wait till you get JIS encodings

Comment: @iqueqiorio: right, because you never specified what codec your data is encoded in, and I picked a common default for XML data. Where did the data come from? Do you have any more context that would let you determine the correct codec?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: or cp1252; neither will *fail* but may not produce readable output if it is the wrong codec.

Comment: `"\xe9".decode("utf8") == ERROR` however in latin1 it is acute e (as noted by @MartijnPieters it also works decoding with "cp1252" ... and if you pick the wrong one you will get problems)

Comment: @iqueqiorio: then the web server can have provided you with the codec, or the XML format itself could have included the codec in the metadata.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay where could I find that info, of what codec they use?

Comment: @iqueqiorio: depends; see [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22583436) for sample code that retrieves the codec if available in the headers. Note that BeautifulSoup will find codec info in the document itself as needed.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example of the problem is:

```
>>> '\xe9'.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`\xe9` isn't an ascii character which means that your string is already encoded. You need to decode it into python's unicode and then encode it again in the serialization format you want.

Since I don't know where your string came from, I just peeked at the [python codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html), picked something from Western Europe and gave it a go:

```
>>> '\xe9'.decode('cp1252')
u'\xe9'
>>> u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa9'
>>>
```

You'll have the best luck if you know exactly which encoding the file came from.

Answer (score 2):

`encode` = turn a unicode string into a bytestring

`decode` = turn a bytestring into unicode

since you already have a bytestring you need decode to make it a unicode instance (assuming that is actually what you are trying to do)

```
output_string = '\n'.join(output_lines)
print output_string.decode("latin1")  #now this returns unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want to do with your lines, you can do different work here, if you just want to print in consul as normally the consuls use `utf8` encoding you dont need to do that by your self as the format of your string is not `unicode`:

```
>>> output_string = '\n'.join(output_lines)
>>> print output_string
<menu>
<day name="monday">
<meal name="BREAKFAST">
<counter name="Entreé">
<dish>
<name icon1="Vegan" icon2="Mindful Item">
Cream of Wheat (Farina)
</name>
</dish>
</counter >
</meal >
</day >
</menu >
```

But if you want to write to file you can use [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module:

```
import codecs
f= codecs.open('out_file','w',encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: or just `"\n".join(output_lines)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah! sorry i miss your answer!