# Character encoding error difficult to handle in code

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

My Python3 application receives from stdin from a external device. The character stream can sometimes have accented characters. The immediate problem is 0xE9, or an accented e. The application looks somewhat like this:

```
while True:
    for raw_line in sys.stdin:
        self.__process_line(raw_line)
```

When the input line containing 0xE9 is encountered, this error occurs:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 7: invalid continuation byte`
so presumably the input stream is not assumed to be UTF-8. If I change this line of code to:
    `self.__process_line(raw_line.encode('latin1'))`
as discussed in other posts on SO related to this error, then this piece of code is happy, but the regexs that process the line fail:

```
__start_order_re = re.compile(r"\AStart Order\s+\d+\Z")
m = self.__start_order_re.match(line)
if m is not None:
    Receipt.__logger("Start of order found")
        self.__reset_state()
```

`TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

If I change the regexes to be byte strings like:
`__start_order_re = re.compile(b"\AStart Order\s+\d+\Z")`
then they succeed, but the errors cascade and every string that interacts with the line similarly fails. This seems wrong. It seems like I should not need to explicitly use `b"` all over with related conversions.

How is the done incorrectly? Where should the character set issues be handled so the code works without explicit managing `b"` data all over the place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ascii codec cant decode byte 0xe9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947607/ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe9)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is what happens after you avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that it was failing differently in operation than in test, so the side effects seen were wrong. It was failing in processing `stdin`, before getting to the app. The problem is described here: [Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding?rq=1), so I needed this change:

```
sys.stdin  = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer,  encoding="latin-1")
while True:
    for raw_line in sys.stdin:
        self.__process_line(raw_line)
```