# Python - Pandas : how to save csv file from url

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

so I'm trying to get a csv file with requests and save it to my project:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

def get_and_save_countries():
    url = 'https://www.trackcorona.live/api/countries'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    data = data["data"]
  
    with open("corona/dash_apps/finished_apps/apicountries.csv","w",newline="") as f:  
        title = "location,country_code,latitude,longitude,confirmed,dead,recovered,updated".split(",") 
        cw = csv.DictWriter(f,title,delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        cw.writeheader()
        cw.writerows(data)
```

I've managed that but when I try this:

```
get_data.get_and_save_countries()
df = pd.read_csv("corona\\dash_apps\\finished_apps\\apicountries.csv")
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

And I have no idea why. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Does anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947607/ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe9) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 with open("corona/dash_apps/finished_apps/apicountries.csv","w",newline="", encoding ='utf-8') as f:
```

to explicitly specify the encoding with `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. It was a minor problem but it saved my entire project.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to a file, the default encoding is `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.  On Windows that is usually not UTF-8 and even on Linux the terminal could be configured other than UTF-8.  Pandas is defaulting to `utf-8`, so specify `encoding='utf8'` as another parameter to `open`.