# Python code not loading php file gives "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte". Trying to load Laravel 8 folder

Tags: python, php

Hello i have coded this program to make class diagram in python but when I am trying to load my Laravel directory and look into php files to generate their class diagram but getting this error even i have put utf-8. Any help will be appreciated.

Code:

```
import os
import re
import tempfile
import webbrowser

# Define the path to the Laravel project
project_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel-8-project'

# Find all the PHP class files in the project
def find_class_files(dir):
    results = []
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        file_path = os.path.join(dir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            results.extend(find_class_files(file_path))
        elif os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.php':
            results.append(file_path)
    return results

# Parse the class names and dependencies from the class files
def parse_classes(class_files):
    classes = []
    for file in class_files:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            contents = f.read()
        class_name = get_class_name(contents)
        if class_name:
            dependencies = get_dependencies(contents)
            classes.append({
                'name': class_name,
                'dependencies': dependencies,
            })
    return classes

# Extract the class name from a PHP class file

# Extract the dependencies from a PHP class file



# Generate an HTML class diagram from a list of classes


# Display an HTML class diagram in the browser


# Find all the PHP class files in the Laravel project
class_files = find_class_files(project_path)

# Parse the class names and dependencies from the class files
classes = parse_classes(class_files)

# Generate the HTML for the class diagram
html = generate_class_diagram(classes)

# Display the class diagram in the browser
display_class_diagram(html)
```

I am getting this error message i dont know whats happening here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\inaqi\Desktop\cd.py", line 77, in <module>
    classes = parse_classes(class_files)
  File "C:\Users\inaqi\Desktop\cd.py", line 25, in parse_classes
    contents = f.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self. Errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 105: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ascii codec cant decode byte 0xe9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947607/ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe9)

Comment: i tried but its not working