# € sign - xlsxwriter error

Tags: python, python-2.7, codec, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to get some data from one web page and write these data into `xlsx` file. Everything seems good but the Encoding error probably raises if it tries to write it into `xlsx` file during CLOSING the file.

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Milano/PycharmProjects/distrelec/crawler.py", line 429, in <module>
    temp_file_to_xlsx()
  File "C:/Users/Milano/PycharmProjects/distrelec/crawler.py", line 119, in temp_file_to_xlsx
    wb.close()    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 295, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 518, in _store_workbook
    xml_files = packager._create_package()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 134, in _create_package
    self._write_workbook_file()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 174, in _write_workbook_file
    workbook._assemble_xml_file()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 464, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_sheets()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 1455, in _write_sheets
    self._write_sheet(worksheet.name, id_num, worksheet.hidden)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 1472, in _write_sheet
    self._xml_empty_tag('sheet', attributes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\xmlwriter.py", line 80, in _xml_empty_tag
    self.fh.write("<%s/>" % tag)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 694, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 357, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To find out where is the problem I've edited `codecs` module:

```
def write(self, object):

        """ Writes the object's contents encoded to self.stream.
        """
        try:
            data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
            self.stream.write(data)
        except:
            print object
            print repr(object)
            raise Exception
```

The output is:

```
<sheet name="Android PCâ€“APC" sheetId="42" r:id="rId42"/>
'<sheet name="Android PC\xe2\x80\x93APC" sheetId="42" r:id="rId42"/>'
    temp_file_to_xlsx()
  File "C:/Users/Milano/PycharmProjects/distrelec/crawler.py", line 119, in temp_file_to_xlsx
    wb.close()    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 295, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 518, in _store_workbook
    xml_files = packager._create_package()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 134, in _create_package
    self._write_workbook_file()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 174, in _write_workbook_file
    workbook._assemble_xml_file()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 464, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_sheets()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 1455, in _write_sheets
    self._write_sheet(worksheet.name, id_num, worksheet.hidden)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 1472, in _write_sheet
    self._xml_empty_tag('sheet', attributes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\xmlwriter.py", line 80, in _xml_empty_tag
    self.fh.write("<%s/>" % tag)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 699, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 363, in write
    raise Exception
Exception
```

What should I do with that please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode your input data with the correct encoding, which seems to be 'utf-8'.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this:

[Example: Simple Unicode with Python 2](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_unicode_python2.html)