# Encoding Emojis with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encode

Looking for some help.  I am working on a project scraping specific Craigslist posts using Beautiful Soup in Python.  I can successfully display emojis found within the post title but have been unsuccessful within the post body.  I've tried different variations but nothing has worked so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
f = open("clcondensed.txt", "w")
html2 = requests.get("https://raleigh.craigslist.org/wan/6078682335.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html2.content,"html.parser")
#Post Title 
title = soup.find(id="titletextonly")       
title1 = soup.title.string.encode("ascii","xmlcharrefreplace")
f.write(title1)
#Post Body  
body = soup.find(id="postingbody")          
body = str(body)
body = body.encode("ascii","xmlcharrefreplace")
f.write(body)
```

Error received from the body:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 273: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Might be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `unicode`

```
body = unicode(body)
```

Please refer Beautiful Soup Documentation [NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring)

---

**Update:**

Sorry for the quick answer. It's not that right.

Here you should use `lxml` parser instead of `html` parser, because `html` parser do not support well for [`NCR (Numeric Character Reference)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) emoji.

In my test, when `NCR` emoji decimal value greater than 65535, such as your html demo emoji `&#128674;`, `HTML` parser just decode it with wrong unicode `\ufffd` than `u"\U0001F6A2"`. I can not find the accurate `Beautiful Soup reference` for this, but the `lxml` parser is just OK.

Below is the tested code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("clcondensed.txt", "w")
html = requests.get("https://raleigh.craigslist.org/wan/6078682335.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "lxml")
#Post Title
title = soup.find(id="titletextonly")
title = unicode(title)
f.write(title.encode('utf-8'))
#Post Body
body = soup.find(id="postingbody")
body = unicode(body)
f.write(body.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

You can ref [lxml entity handling](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html#entity-handling) to do more things.

If you do not install `lxml`, just ref [lxml installing](http://lxml.de/installation.html).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the help and linked references.  Worked as expected.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Phil21 I am glad that help