# find arabic word string in string give error 'ascii' codec can't decode

Tags: python, unicode, arabic

i write this function for check if month in persian exist in uicode string, replace
it with number of month .
i use this encode in header

```
`#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
```

this is my def to convert month

```
def changeData(date):
                if date:
                   date.encode('utf-8')
                    if "فروردین".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":فروردین", ":1")
                    elif "اردیبهشت".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":اردیبهشت", ":2")
                    elif "خرداد".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":خرداد", ":3")
                    elif "تیر".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":تیر", ":41")
                    elif "مرداد".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":مرداد", ":5")
                    elif "شهریور".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":شهریور", ":6")
                    elif "مهر".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":مهر", ":7")
                    elif "آبان".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":آبان", ":8")
                    elif "آذر".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":آذر", ":9")
                    elif "دی".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":دی", ":10")
                    elif "بهمن".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":بهمن", ":11")
                    elif "اسفند".encode('utf-8') in date:
                        return str.replace(":اسفند", ":12")
```

i pass date with unicode format in function then convert it to `encode('utf-8')` but give me this error

```
if "فروردین".encode('utf-8') in date:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how i can solve this problem

Comment: Do you use Python 2.7?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Python 2.7.

---

So:

```
"فروردین".encode('utf-8') # UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The problem is the fact that in Python 2.7 strings are bytes:

```
print(repr("فروردین")) # '\xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd8\xaf\xdb\x8c\xd9\x86'
```

With the following code:

```
"فروردین".encode('utf-8')
```

you're trying to encode bytes which is logically incorrect because:

```
ENCODING: unicode --> bytes 
DECODING: bytes --> unicode
```

But Python doesn't throw smth like `TypeError`, because Python is smart.
In such a case it tries first to decode the given bytes to unicode and then execute encoding specified by user.
The problem is that Python does the described decoding with a default encoding which is `ASCII` in Python 2. Therefore the program terminates with the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

The described decoding is similar to the:

```
unicode("فروردین") # UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

So, you shouldn't encode byte-string and you have to **DECODE** it in order to receive unicode:

```
u = "فروردین".decode('utf-8') 
print(type(u)) # <type 'unicode'>
```

Another way to get unicode is to use `u`-literal + encoding declaration:

```
# coding: utf-8

u = u"فروردین"
print(type(u)) # <type 'unicode'> 

print(u == "فروردین".decode('utf-8')) # True
```

Comment: or just declare utf-8 in the source file, and prefix the strings with `u` like in `u"فروردین"` - that way calling `decode` is not necessary.

Comment: @jsbueno, agreed